# "More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'" when adding modules to project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have an Android Studio project to which I am adding an SDK. The SDK is compromised of about 4 different modules. The problem is when I add the modules I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':appName:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforces in 1.0
```

I have gone through the majority of the Stackoverflow answers on this and have narrowed down what I think the problem is, unfortunately none of the other answers seem to match my situation.

Here are the dependencies for my app build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile project(':sdk')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

As you can see I have added the play-services dependancy

Here is part of the build.gradle dependancies for my sdk module:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87')
    {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

This is where I think the problem is coming from, having two dependancies which contain the google.android.gms.

The issue is that if I remove this code from my sdk module then I get the following error:

[image]

If I remove the dependancy in the gradle.build of my main app file I get lots of errors like this:

[image]

I have gone through almost all of the other answers but they mainly seem to be the case that two dependancies have been added when one will do rather than a problem that seems to span modules.

It seems to me that there must be a way to link the sdk module to the google_play_services_version number in my main app but I just can't figure out how to do it.

If anyone has any advice it would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will usually happen when you have **duplicate** **libraries**, in your case
**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'** already includes the **maps** lib, try to crunch it down to the "**service**" that you *actually* want to implement, [here is a list](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) or grab it from below

- Google+  com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
- Google Account Login com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
- Google Actions, Base Client
  Library  com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
- Google Address
  API  com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
- Google App
  Indexing com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
- Google App
  Invites  com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
- Google Analytics com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
- Google Cast  com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0    Google
  Cloud
- Messaging    com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
- Google Drive com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
- Google Fit   com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
- Google Location, Activity Recognition, and
  Places   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
- Google Maps  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
- Google Mobile Ads    com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
- Mobile Vision    com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
- Google Nearby    com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
- Google Panorama
  Viewer   com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
- Google Play Game
  services com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
- SafetyNet    com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
- Google Wallet    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
- Android Wear com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0

**Hope it helps**